# Installing/Formatting second hard drive- Single Partition

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have recently purchased a 3TB WD Green hard drive and am trying to run it as internal storage.  I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04 on a 250GB WD harddrive.  The OS was just installed so nothing really has been altered.

I have tried to partition the drive using GParted and the command prompt but get errors either way.

I get a warning in the command prompt when I use `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb` as follows:

```
WARNING: The size of this disk is 3.0 TB (3000592982016 bytes). 
DOS partition table format can not be used on drives for volumes larger than 
 (2199023255040 bytes) for 512-byte sectors. 
Use parted(1) and GUID partition table format (GPT).
```

The device presents a logical sector size that is smaller than the physical sector size. Aligning to a physical sector (or optimal I/O) size boundary is recommended, or performance may be impacted.

This is my first time using a linux based system so unfortunately I don't know what to do from here.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have created two smaller partitions of type ext4.  They have been mounted but I do not have privileges to write to the partitions.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using `Gparted`, it should fix your issue.  Past that just use GPT.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning:** As this is a new drive, the following steps **will delete everything on your drive!!!**

Go to the dash and start `gparted`:

[image: Parted screen]

Then select the drive in the upper right corner (where on the picture you can see `/dev/sde`)

Go to the "Device" menu and choose "create partition table".
(You will get a huge warning that this will delete your entire disk.) Click on the "Select new Partition table type" and take `gpt`.

**And now you can do whatever you want!** (including creating one huge partition)